# Wagtail 2.11 translatable field with wagtai-localize

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to translate a non snipppet/page model in Wagtail >= 2.11 and wagtail-localize >= 0.9.3 ?

I've set up my model as follows:

```
class TrainingPlace(TranslatableMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta(TranslatableMixin.Meta):
        verbose_name = "Training Places"

    translatable_fields = [
        TranslatableField("description")
    ]
```

I have a "Training" submenu in my wagtail admin page, with Trainings, Training Photos, Trainers, Training Places, where I can add Trainers, new Trainings etc.

If I register a TraningPlace with a `@register_snipppet` I can translate it, but at the moment there are some problems:

- I see many Trainings (menu) -> TrainingPlace recoreds in admin listing with no "Translate" option
- If I go to Snippets (menu) => Training Place snippets I can see snipppets and have option to translate/create/sync translations, but when I click on change language button in admin I am getting a blank page (url points to a snippet with different ID) which may be a bug.

Can non snippet/page models be translated in admin when using TranslatableMixin on model ?

Comment: Try to delete and migrate your database if it's possible. I think something happened with that tag which you are getting when translating a snippet. And did you add TranslatableMixin to that class when you already had tags?

Comment: You need to "sync" translations with snippets. You should see all your main snippets, once you have a new Locale to choose from a new menu option will appear and you can click "Sync translated snippets". That will create the translated object in the database. Once that object exists, you can perform proper translations on it. This exists in multiple steps so we don't have to add a new field to every model field for every language.